# Vimをデーモンとして立ち上げる方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: vim

Vimをデーモンとして立ち上げる方法を探しています。
Vimのプロセスを常に起動しておき、ターミナルからアクセスする時に
毎回同じプロセスのvimを使いたいと思っています。

理由としては、Vimのプラグインであるjedi-vimを使っているのですが、
毎回numpyなどの大きなライブラリを補完すると、初期化が走りしばらく待たされます。
二回目からはメモリ上にキャッシュされるらしいので、非常に早くていいのですが、
うっかりVimを閉じてしまうと、再度起動した時に再び読み込みがされるので面倒です。
これをVimをデーモン化することで解決したいと思っています。

色々調べた所、emacsではデーモン化ができてるようなので、
同じことをVimで実現したいと思っています。
- emacsをデーモン化すると超便利 - 射撃しつつ前転 http://d.hatena.ne.jp/tkng/20090203/1233662327
- emacs daemon で使う - Qiita http://qiita.com/yukifrog/items/5928f434c3342c9cab4d

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 5):

デーモン化するという事は、tty を切り離して新しい仮想端末を作り、接続されたクライアントと通信する必要がありますが Vim にはデーモン化する実装はありません。
tmux を使ってそこ上で Vim を起動しておくのが現状可能な策かと思います。

Answer (score 3):

vim server mode はだめなのでしょうか？

これは+clientserverでコンパイルされていれば使用できる機能で、`vim --serverlist`の結果が存在すれば、`vim --remote (編集したいファイル)`とすると既に起動しているvimでそのファイルが開きます。
`vim --serverlist`の結果が存在しない場合、予め`vim --servername VIM`としてVimを起動しておくと上手くいくかと思います。

詳細は`:help clientserver`して確認してください。